# Kähler differentials give a left Quillen functor

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, model-categories

Is there a reference for the fact that the functor of Kähler differentials is a left Quillen functor on the category of $\mathrm{CDGA}_k/B$? Here $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$, and $B$ is some CDGA.

This seems easy to prove, but I would appreciate a reference in the existing literature.

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4628858/kahler-differentials-give-a-left-quillen-functor) from MSE.

Comment: I think you answered this yourself, on page 33 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.12699.pdf. Care to come back an add an answer below, so this doesn't linger unanswered forever?